# Haskell: for each (k,v) in Map, do IO() with k and v

Tags: haskell, dictionary, io, functional-programming, purely-functional

I have a `Map (Int,Int) Char`and I'm trying to draw each `Char`s in it at the position contained in the key. My functions are:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as SM
data Position = Position !GLint !GLint

drawMirrors :: SM.Map (Int,Int) Char -> IO()
drawMirrors mirrors = do
    mapM_ (\(x,y) c -> drawMirror c (Position x y)) mirrors

drawMirror :: Char -> Position -> IO()
drawMirror orientation (Position x y) = do
    -- Some irrelevant stuff
```

At the `drawMirrors mirrors = do mapM_ (\(x,y) c -> drawMirror c (Position x y)) mirrors` line, I'm getting the error:

> ```
> src\Main.hs:200:33:
>
> Couldn't match expected type `Char -> IO ()'
>             with actual type `IO b0'
> The lambda expression `\ (x, y) c -> drawMirror c (Position y)'
> has two arguments,
> but its type `(t0, GLint) -> IO b0' has only one
> In the first argument of `mapM_', namely
>   `(\ (x, y) c -> drawMirror c (Position y))'
> In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>   mapM_ (\ (x, y) c -> drawMirror c (Position y)) mirrors
> ```

How can I, in `drawMirrors`, get all the keys and values in the dictionary and apply the `drawMirror` function with these keys and values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lambda, `\(x,y) c -> drawMirror c (Position x y)`, takes two arguments. However, it is called with a single argument of the form `(key, value)` (in your case `((x, y), c)`.

```
(\((x,y), c) -> drawMirror c (Position x y))
```

Moreover, `mapM_` (which I believe in your case is from `Data.Foldable`) only iterate over the keys, so you might want to call [`SM.toList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3) to have a list of `(key, value)`.

The final result is :

```
drawMirrors :: SM.Map (Int,Int) Char -> IO()
drawMirrors mirrors = do
    mapM_ (\((x,y), c) -> drawMirror c (Position x y)) $ SM.toList mirrors
```

Comment: It should work  to write `\((x, y), c) -> drawMirror c (Position y)`

Comment: My mistake, I think I just forgot a comma. Thanks, I'll fix my answer.

Comment: You might also like [mapWithKeyM_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys-3.10.1/docs/Data-Key.html#v:mapWithKeyM_).

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this, and have found one way to use `mapM_` instead of `mapWithKeyM_`. Specifically,

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data UnCurry :: (* -> * -> *) -> * -> * where
  UnCurry :: f k v -> UnCurry f (k, v)

instance Foldable (UnCurry Map) where
  foldr c n (UnCurry m) = M.foldrWithKey go n m
    where
      go k a b = c (k, a) b
```

Now you can use `mapM_ f (UnCurry m)` to perform an action for each key-value pair in a `Map`.